# Dynamic forms is not working in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

Error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'question' since it isn't a known property of 'app-question'.

1. If 'app-question' is an Angular component and it has 'question' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-question' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

   ][question]="question" [form]="form">

problem occurs in for loop angular is saying app-question is component.

dynamicform ts

```
            import { Component, Input, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
            import { FormGroup }                 from '@angular/forms';

            import { QuestionBase }              from './question-base';
            import { QuestionControlService }    from './question-control.service';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
              templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
              providers: [ QuestionControlService ]
            })
            export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

              @Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
              form: FormGroup;
              payLoad = '';

              constructor(private qcs: QuestionControlService) {  }

              ngOnInit() {
                this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
              }

              onSubmit() {
                this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
              }
            }
```

dynamic form component.html

```
            <div>
              <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">

                <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
                  <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
                </div>
              </form>

              <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
                <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
              </div>
            </div>
```

Error code

```
   <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
              <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
            </div>
```

problem

> There is no component **question** in tutorial they are accessing as component.

Solution

> It presents a list of questions, each bound to a  component element. The  tag matches the DynamicFormQuestionComponent, the component responsible for rendering the details of each individual question based on values in the data-bound question object.

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-question',
   templateUrl: './dynamic-form-question.component.html'
   })
```

> so the confusion was i was thinking app-question was component but it was selector.

Url

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jamlyparydld

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

- any solution is most welcome

Comment: Post the code of your question component, and a stackblitz reproducing the issue (as the one you have provided doesn't seem to reproduce it)

Comment: in tutorial there is no component as question  that's why  error appear  i don't know angular has used question which is not a component

Comment: app-question is not a angular framework base component, that's for sure.